# Is it feasible to create an responsive website and mobile application with same codebase?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

Being said that IBM Mobilefirst is very advanced tool in developing hybrid mobile applications, I am curious to know if we can develop both the mobile application and the responsive mobile application using single code base. I know that there are different environments being provided out of box by Mobilefirst i.e mobile browser, desktopBrowser, Android etc.. I feel it kind of opens an option to developer to develop both mobile and responsive web application. But following questions and functionalities makes me rethink about going forward with this approach for practical implementation.

1) How far will the MobileFirst be reusable and flexible in terms of: 
* implementing session management for both applications
* Authentication and Authorisation for both applications: 
  - When I said Authorisation, I meant user level preferences
2) What are the steps that need to be followed to setup a project which effectively uses the all the key features of the worklight for satisfying the above mentioned requirement. 
3) Post development what are the steps that need to be followed to successfully deploy mobile and web application (Both of them will be using adapters to talk to services) into production.

Very sorry for making the question so theoretical. I felt very interesting and wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How far will the MobileFirst be reusable and flexible in terms of:
>   * implementing session management for both applications
>   * Authentication and Authorisation for both applications:
>   - When I said Authorisation, I meant user level preferences

- Depends which version of MFPF you are using.

  - Pre-7.1, all session management is the same in the server.
  - 7.1 forward the server is session independent and currently Mobile Web and Desktop Browser are not supported; read more about session independent in the IBM Knowledge Center
- Authentication works the same for both pretty much

> 2) What are the steps that need to be followed to setup a project which effectively uses the all the key features of the worklight for satisfying the above mentioned requirement.

There is not feature parity between the supported mobile environment and web environment, so the answer will depend on which particular features you will end up using. The IBM Knowledge Center contains a feature parity table.

> 3) Post development what are the steps that need to be followed to successfully deploy mobile and web application (Both of them will be using adapters to talk to services) into production.

That's got nothing to do with any of the environment you'll choose to use. It's the same for all. Yet again, read in the IBM Knowledge Center.

Comment: How about authorisation ?
Does mobileFirst provide authorisation component like IBM websphere portal Which can restrict user with a specific role from not accessing a page or content if he don't have rights?